# null InputStream Android (When used dynamic feature module)

Tags: android, kotlin

[AppDoctor] null InputStream [CONTEXT service_id=254 ]

```
BoxUtil com.google.android.gms.persistent E [AppDoctor] null InputStream [CONTEXT service_id=254 ]
java.io.IOException: null InputStream

at csij.d(:com.google.android.gms@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-580326705):209)
at csgr.l(:com.google.android.gms@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-580326705):7)
at csgi.apply(:com.google.android.gms@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-580326705):35)
at com.google.android.gms.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-580326705):481)
at com.google.android.gms.framework.tracing.wrapper.TracingIntentService.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-580326705):14)
at njh.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@234414038@23.44.14 (190400-580326705):7)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

In my project, when the dynamic feature module is available and I generate a signed APK, my app crashes. After removing the dynamic feature module, the app works.